# Is it possible to generate '_id' as just numbers in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, microservices

I am implementing Microservices in Flask application.

Service A runs on MySQL and Service B runs on MongoDB using pymongo.

The ID from Service B is linked as an Integer field in MySQL.

Is it possible to make MongoDB generate '_id' as a sequence of just numbers instead of alphanumeric characters or should I go about changing the schema of MySQL ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongo directly won't do that, But you can do that by yourself. Send _id as a unique number to mongo while storing as document and it will accept it.

```
> db.a.insert({_id:111})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

In fact you can use auto-incremented _ids as well using [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)